# How to turn textual qualified data to a tree

Tags: c#, data-structures, tree, treeview

I have data that looks like the below:

```
a.b.c.d.e.f.g
b.c.d.e.f.g.h.x
c.d.e.q.s.n.m.y
a.b.c
```

I need to take this data and turn each and every level into a node in a treeview. So the tree looks something like:

```
a
  b
    c
      d
        e
...
b
  c
    d
....
```

if for example at the same leve there is another a, elements under this should be added as nodes to that branch. I have thought of the following:

1. Parse each line that is qualified by the dot character for each element and create an ordered list.
2. For each item in the list add it as a node in the current location.
3. Before adding check to make sure another item at the same level does not exist with the same name.
4. Add the next element until all items in the list are done, next elements being child to the first added item of the list.

I hope I was clear and let me know if it needs further clarification.

Comment: It looks like you already have a solution to your problem. What's your question?

Comment: I believe my solution is a shitty one :) Honestly trying to understand how this is tackled by more experienced programmers.

Comment: You're on the right track. There are some options when it comes to implementing each step, but at the high level your solution is exactly what I'd do. Give it a try and post your code at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Recursion is the way to go for this, look at my answer below. This is exactly how the contents of the file system are loaded into a tree view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the Node class to have the checks, if you want a list of children nodes, etc, add that as a HashSet, so you can easily make the check for uniqueness.  Add a method in the Node class to do the AddChild and do the check on the HashSet.

```
public class Main
    {
        public Main()
        {
            string treeStr = "";

            string[] strArr = { "a.b.c.d.e.f.g", "b.c.d.e.f.g.h.x" };

            List<Node> nodes = new List<Node>();
            Node currentNode;

            foreach (var str in strArr)
            {
                string[] split = str.Split('.');
                currentNode = null;

                for (int i = 0; i < split.Length; i++)
                {
                    var newNode = new Node { Value = str };

                    if (currentNode != null)
                    {
                        currentNode.Child = newNode;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        nodes.Add(newNode);
                    }

                    currentNode = newNode;
                }
            }
        }


    }

    public class Node
    {
        public string Value { get; set; }
        public Node Child { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, this will generate the text output but my question is how to turn each of those padded children into nodes. They also need to be the child of the previously added node element until all list is done.

Comment: @driverobject I didn't add the check for you, but explained a bit of how you can do that, using the Node class to do the work for you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming the existence of the methods `CreateRootNode` and `AddChildNode`.

```
void ParseToTreeview(IEnumerable<string> data) {
    foreach (var line in data) {
        var names = line.Split('.');
        for (var i = 0; i < names.Length; i++) {
            TreeNode node = null;
            if (i == 0)
                node = CreateRootNode(name:names[i]);
            else
                node = AddChildNode(name:names[i], parentNode:node);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A recursive method to add all of these is what you need. Here's a sample:

Use:

```
string[] yourListOfData = { "a.b.c.d.e.f.g", "b.c.d.e.f.g.h.x", "c.d.e.q.s.n.m.y", "a.b.c" };
foreach(string x in yourListOfData)
  PopulateTreeView(x, myTreeView.Nodes[0]);
```

Sample Method:

```
  public void PopulateTreeView(string values, TreeNode parentNode )
  {
      string nodeValue = values;
      string additionalData = values.Substring(value.Length - (value.Length - 2));

      try
      {
         if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(nodeValue))
         {
            TreeNode myNode = new TreeNode(nodeValue);
            parentNode.Nodes.Add(myNode);
            PopulateTreeView(additionalData, myNode);
         }
      } catch ( UnauthorizedAccessException ) {
        parentNode.Nodes.Add( "Access denied" );
      } // end catch
  }
```

**NOTE:** code above is not tested, might need tweaking